# Remapping a URL to a MVC application

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm remaking a website, previous build on DotNetNuke. I need to keep the database, as old URLs working.

The issue: translate the old URL

eq.

```
http://localhost:8069/Noticias/tabid/78/language/pt-BR/nid/2267/Palestra-
discute-o-futuro-profissional-das-crianca.aspx
```

to the new mapping engine, that would be something like that:

eq.

```
http://localhost:8069/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}
```

where, in the example, 2267 is my *id*, and 78 is the module id that i have to 'translate' for a controller name. The action is *view* by default.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do these exist in the same application, or is it two distinct web apps?

Comment: the database will be ported to the new MVC application and DNN will exist no more

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a base page handler for the requests you want to transfer, and then do a simple `Response.Redirect` to the appropriate URL on your new website then. All your pages inherit these changes, and you can provide a listing of URLs in a configuration file or database for the URLs to dynamically redirect.